# How do I organize a character's modular equipment for a game engine?

Tags: objects, export, blend-files

Say that I want a character with many modular sets of clothing and weapons, I don't want them all to be loaded in at the same time as the character they're attached to in Godot (as I believe it would be inefficient, resource wise, to do that).

Is there some tool to help with this, or what would be the recommended course of action?
I want to get this right before jumping into creating a bunch of different items and then realizing I've made a bunch of work for myself.

When importing them into the Godot game engine, I would prefer not having a giant blend file containing every mesh, where I'd need to manually save each equipment mesh to a distinct scene (scenes being the files containing objects that can be loaded in separately within the engine). I'd also likely need to do this every time I make a change to a model or an animation.

---

To avoid doing some of the above busywork:

An idea would be to mark certain objects in the blend file to be exported separately or to be saved as a separate file (while preserving its rigging ofc) if that's possible.

It doesn't seem to be possible to have multiple blender files open remotely, so that I can break up the character's blend file into a bunch of different files **AND** still be able to animate them together. If I do save my clothes and weapons in separate .blend files, how on earth do I make sure they are animated correctly (i.e. not clipping through the character) and be able to make adjustments?

pls halp.